# Broken UI on devices with small screen size - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui

So basically I have already crafted my UI and it works just fine if it wasnt for the fact that my UI/Stacks do not seem to be fitting into devices with smaller screens such as the iPod Touch 7th gen or the iPhone SE 2nd gen. I was under the impression that if I avoided hardcoded frames and went with dynamic elements such as the spacing parameter on stacks, .padding, Spacer(), etc. then SwiftUI would do its layout magic and it would work across multiple screen sizes. Im not even using complex views here, its just a couple stacks & Text views.

Code:

```
struct EntireView: View {
var viewModel: ViewModel
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HeadView(vm: viewModel)
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: 1)
        FieldView(viewModel: viewModel)
        ButtonView()
    }
}
```

}

```
struct HeadView: View {

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Text("some text")
                .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.bold, size: 16))
            Text(vm.description)
                .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.semibold, size: 14))
        }
        .padding()
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("some text")
                        .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.bold, size: 16))
                    Text("some text")
                        .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.regular, size: 12))
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("some text")
                        .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.bold, size: 16))
                    Text(""some text")
                        .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.regular, size: 12))
                }
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Text("some text")
                        .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.bold, size: 16))
                    Text("some text")
                        .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.regular, size: 12))
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        HStack {
            Text("some text")
                .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.italic, size: 14))
            Spacer()
            Text("some text")
                .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.bold, size: 14))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 69, height: 25)
                .background(.green)
                .cornerRadius(4)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

}

```
struct FieldView: View {
let viewModel: HoldingDetailViewModel

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            HStack {
                Text("some text")
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .frame(width: 1, height: 25)
                Text("some text")
            }
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
            Text("some text")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        
    }
    .font(.custom(FontType.OpenSans.semibold, size: 14))
}
```

On smaller devices, theres elements not even being rendered as they do not fit the screen, how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: It would be helpful to formulate your code as an [mre] that anyone could compile. Or, at least provide screenshots. In general, SwiftUI solves a ton of layout issues with responsive design. However, if you just have too much stuff to fit on the screen, it can't solve that for you. For example, I don't see any `ScrollView`s in your code, which you'd have to include if it's going to be too large in the vertical direction.

Comment: Also, in general, I'd avoid doing things like `UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20` -- use `padding` instead.

Comment: Firstly, my apologies for not providing an actual reproducible example, I stripped part of the code to avoid ending with an enormous thread.
Secondly, I just tested a ScrollView and that just might be the solution, as I guess the contents i am trying to fit on the screen literally do not fit on smaller screens and it wouldnt be doable even in UIKit, right? I thought I was missing something SwiftUI related, but it may just be that the elements literally do not fit in the screen and a scrollview is mandatory.
Lastly, noted on avoiding UIScreen, I aggre padding is a far better approach. Thanks!

Comment: You are correct that it "wouldn't be doable even in UIKit" -- there's no getting around having too much content in a certain direction (unless you continue to shrink fonts, images, etc). Remember, also, that you should accommodate users' accessibility settings like font sizes (which SwiftUI gives you for free, but you're overriding with explicit font sizes) which will make the content grow even more.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how it 'breaks' the View on smaller screen sizes? That would be helpful

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! I ended up making part of my UI scrollable to ensure all the stacks have enough space and it now works great even on the smallest of screens. Thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have stacked so many Vertical Stacks on top of each other, that the UI builder simply runs out of physical screen estate to render all your UI elements.

I think what you want to use is a `ScrollView` like this:

```
struct EntireView: View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            HeadView(vm: viewModel)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: 1)
            FieldView(viewModel: viewModel)
            ButtonView()
        }
    }
}
```

This way, all UI elements are rendered in a large `VStack` so to say, which you can scroll through. Thus, not limited to the phyiscal screen size. Is this what you wanted?

If you desire some parts of your Views to be scrollable and some not, you can do the following for example:

```
struct EntireView: View {
    var viewModel: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HeadView(vm: viewModel)
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            
                 Rectangle()
                     .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20, height: 1)
                 FieldView(viewModel: viewModel)
                 ButtonView()
             }
        }
        
    }
}
```

This way, the `HeadView` stays in position at the top of the screen and the other contents will be scrollable.

Comment: YES! This is exactly what was going on, for whatever reason I thought I had something wrong with the layout and I was missing something with SwiftUI, but it ended up being literally not having enough physical space to render all the stacks, haha, newbie mistake! So a scrollview did the trick.

Super thankful for the second part as well, I actually used that case and made only a few parts of my UI scrollable! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @stompy, if Björn solved your issue please mark it as the correct answer so other people having the same issue will find easily the solution :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Good luck on your Swift journey :)

Comment: Thanks! By the looks of it, I will definitely need it haha.